# Import data from Coinmarketcap.com to Google Sheets using Apps Script and API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write code in Google Apps Script that will dump the data shown on the url https://coinmarketcap.com/  into a Google Sheet (say starting in A1). Not just data for one symbol, but all the symbols shown on this page. Specifically I am looking for the data for 'symbol' 'name' 'price' 'market_cap' .

The API documentation is here: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest

I used to use an API connector to do this, but would rather a couple of lines of code. I spent a couple of hours reading about different approaches from search results, but they were either appropriate for a single symbol, or involved too many requests.

My code is below. I am not getting error, but it isn't returning any data either. I believe I need to tweak 'setValue' but am not sure how to do it.

Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
function coin_price() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Coins')
  var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?aux=cmc_rank',
  qs: {
   start: '1',
   limit: '5000',
   convert: 'USD',
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'MY API KEY'
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true,
};

var url = `https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?aux=cmc_rank`;
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
var txt = result.getContentText()
var d = JSON.parse(txt);
sheet.getRange(100,1).setValue(d.data.market_cap)
}
```

Comment: I have no api_key, so can you provide a copy of `result.getContentText()`?

Comment: I outputted the log to this file https://docs.google.com/document/d/15cAEHQDPjzp6uL7Cr0fOglmNZ_cvDOQeanl6AOPqOVA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is a log of 'd'

Comment: ok thx, I will try to understand the structure even if I haven't a complete response

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: You will find an answer below, I let you with @Irvin Jay G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggestion

Perhaps you can try this tweaked script below:

### Script:

```
function coin_price() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Coins')
  var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?aux=cmc_rank',
  qs: {
   start: '1',
   limit: '5000',
   convert: 'USD',
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'API_Key'
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true,
};

var url = `https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?aux=cmc_rank`;
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
var txt = result.getContentText()
var d = JSON.parse(txt);
var dSymbol = [];
var name = [];
var price = [];
var marketCap = [];
for(i=0; i<d.data.length; i++){
  marketCap.push([d.data[i].quote.USD.market_cap]);
  dSymbol.push([d.data[i].symbol]);
  name.push([d.data[i].name]);
  price.push([d.data[i].quote.USD.price])
}
//getRange structure (starting row, start col, total number of rows,total number of cols)
sheet.getRange(1,1,dSymbol.length,1).setValues(dSymbol); //Symbol in Col A (start col #1)
sheet.getRange(1,2,name.length,1).setValues(name); //Name in Col B (start col #2)
sheet.getRange(1,3,price.length,1).setValues(price); //Price in Col C (start col #3)
sheet.getRange(1,4,marketCap.length,1).setValues(marketCap); //Market Cap in Col D (start col #4)
}
```

### Sample Result:

> [image]

### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: @user31445 I hope this helps. Feel free to let me know if there's anything missing.

Comment: Hi Irvin thank you. The script runs and generates data in the log (Logging output too large. Truncating output) , but does not seem to copy it to the sheet.

Comment: Hmm... did you try replacing your current script with the tweaked script above? My tweaked script doesn't have any logging like `Logger.log()`.

Comment: For some reason when I copied over the old script, it wasn't working. So I created a new script and works great. Thank you very much!